# Using a base class for unit test setup and teardown

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

Assuming Visual Studio.NET 2008 and MsTest are used to run unit tests. When a system is based on a service container and dependency injection unit testing would naturally require the setting up of services.

Should these services rather be setup in a base class that all unit tests derive from or in each unit test class. If they should be in a base class, is there a way to have the `TestInitialize` and `ClassInitialize` methods be executed without requiring them to be called from the derived class, e.g base.Initialise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MSTest framework will search the entire object (all base classes) for the methods marked `Test*`. Like when you declare them on the unit test class, you do not have to call them explicitly.

Comment: Class* methods will always be marked as static and hence will not be called from derived classes. The Test* methods will be called since they are instance methods.

Answer (score 6):

With 2008, you should be able to have [TestInitialize] on a base class, and as long as you don't add another [TestInitialize] somewhere down the hierarchy, it should be called. You could also do things with virtual methods.

Comment: Works for [TearDown] and other similar identifiers as well.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `Test*` and `Class*` marked methods to be on the actual unit test class. If you define them on a base class, you cannot add test specific activities to them. Instead, use the static and instance constructors and finalizer on your base class.